# a simple bookmarklet to refresh the button?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarklet

How do I reload the current web page using a bookmarklet?

I am looking for a way to add the reload functionality to the bookmark bar as I failed to locate an extension for the same that could be added to the right side of the chrome omnibar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would *probably* be better server on SuperUser but...

```
javascript:location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. With the help of a friend, I was able to get a custom extension for Chrome! http://www.mediafire.com/?z3ttlcpduq89bz9